# mysql -u root sql -> blog.sql

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I was trying to migrate my WordPress blog from the server and somehow I corrupted my sql database.

I have typed these commands into my Centos VPS:

```
mysqldump -u root -QqeR --add-drop-table --databases blogsql -> blog.sql
mysql -u root blogsql -> blog.sql
mysql -u root blogsql > blog.sql
mysql -u root -p blogsql > blog.sql
mysql -u root -p blogsql > blog.sql
mysql -u root -p blogsql > blog.sql
mysql -u root -p blogsql > blog.sql
mysql -u root blogsql > blog.sql
```

Comment: how do I contact you? skype would be best

Comment: Use "<" instead of ">" when importing via mysql! mysql -u root -p blogsql < blog.sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using the wrong operator.

`>` redirects output which is what you want for the dump

`<` is what you want to restore

so 
`mysql -u root -p blogsql < blog.sql` should import it

also typo in the first line

`mysqldump -u root -QqeR --add-drop-table --databases blogsql -> blog.sql`

should be

`mysqldump -u root -QqeR --add-drop-table --databases blogsql > blog.sql`

Comment: I'm not trying to import. I was trying to export my database and it took for 30minutes and after that the whole database got corrupted.

Comment: Your trying to do both by the look of it the top command exports

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the help, the database was not corrupted, just iptables was blocking my 80port so I thought I have overwitten the database, but it had no issues.

anyways thank you for the help guys!